# Stacking mails which are sent after long time

Tags: email, gmail, amazon-ses

I am using SES as mail server and gmail as service provider.

Gmail stacks mail based on subject, but for short time. If 2 mails with same subject in short duration, the emails get stacked in the same thread. But if the mails are sent after delay like 1 day, the mails get split.

Is there any way to thread/stack the mails.
One solution is to get the `messageId` of the first mail, store it in database or some persistent layer and send other mails using `In_Reply-To` header and its value as previous `mesageId`.

Other solution I found is to add `References` header with some value and to send same value in all mails where we want to stack them.

But the 2nd solution didnt work. The first solution needs more effort to build so I am not looking forward for it.

Is there any other solution around the 2nd solution so that I can create a some random value for mails which needs to be in the same thread/stacked.